# Given 3 points, how do I calculate the normal vector?

Tags: c#, math, .net-3.5, geometry

Given three 3D points (A,B, & C) how do I calculate the normal vector? The three points define a plane and I want the vector perpendicular to this plane.

Can I get sample C# code that demonstrates this?

Comment: Math has a lot to do with programming.  Especially this math, if you're doing anything 3D.

Comment: Give him a break, it's marked C# and .net-3.5. This is a problem that comes up immediately when you start *programming* 3D apps. Look at the related questions, we usually allow this stuff.

Comment: My decision line is: will the math that is being asked about be implemented *in code*. As it will, this gets to stay.

Comment: @NoonSilk: StackOverflow postings are read by other visitors, possibly a long time after they have been written (as you can see by my finding this question six years after your comment). Keeping questions that ought to be closed in a *closed* state and questions that ought to remain open in an *open* state is just a part of the usual curating to keep everything tidy for future visitors.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It depends on the order of the points. If the points are specified in a counter-clockwise order as seen from a direction **opposing** the normal, then it's simple to calculate:

```
Dir = (B - A) x (C - A)
Norm = Dir / len(Dir)
```

where `x` is the cross product.

If you're using OpenTK or XNA (have access to the Vector3 class), then it's simply a matter of:

```
class Triangle {
    Vector3 a, b, c;
    public Vector3 Normal {
        get {
            var dir = Vector3.Cross(b - a, c - a);
            var norm = Vector3.Normalize(dir);
            return norm;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Form the cross-product of vectors BA and BC.  See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html.

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate the [cross product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html) of any two non-parallel vectors on the surface.  Since you have three points, you can figure this out by taking the cross product of, say, vectors AB and AC.

When you do this, you're calculating a [surface normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_normal), of which Wikipedia has a pretty extensive explanation.