# Normal Vector to a plane

Tags: math, graphics, geometry, linear-algebra

I have 3 points P1(x1, y1), P2(x2,y2) & P3(x3, y3).
How do I find the vector normal to the plane passing through these 3 points?

Comment: google rocks !!!
first rsult : http://jtaylor1142001.net/calcjat/Solutions/VPlanes/VP3Pts.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [Given 3 pts, how do I calculate the normal vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966587/given-3-pts-how-do-i-calculate-the-normal-vector)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly there is a missing coordinate Z in your points...

Assuming

```
p1 = x1, y1, z1
p2 = x2, y2, z2
p3 = x3, y3, z3
```

then the normal is proportional to

```
nx = (y2 - y1)*(z3 - z1) - (z2 - z1)*(y3 - y1)
ny = (z2 - z1)*(x3 - x1) - (x2 - x1)*(z3 - z1)
nz = (x2 - x1)*(y3 - y1) - (y2 - y1)*(x3 - x1)
```

This is the method suggested by Kerrek SB, with explicit formulas. In vector notation:

```
n = (p2 - p1) ^ (p3 - p1)
```

Comment: ... although you could argue that given those three points, the plane is simply `z = 0` so the normal is `(0, 0, 1)` :)

Answer (score 3):

Take one point as the base point, compute the two difference vectors to the other two points (those two span the plane), and take their cross product to get a normal vector. Pay attention to orientation if signs matter.