# What exactly is "normal" data?(direct3d 11, c++)

Tags: c++, direct3d11

I heard the term normal data many times before in direct3d games. But I never knew what it means. I tried searching in google for results, but most of them gave vague explanations about Normal data.

From what i understand, normal data is used for lighting calculations, such as diffusion, ambient and directional. But that's pretty much all i understand..

Can someone explain to me why we use normal data? and what exactly is normal data?

Answer (score 2):

In graphics usually referring to the vector that's perpendicular to a surface: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)

Comment: And if you need to calculate yours, this might help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966587/given-3-pts-how-do-i-calculate-the-normal-vector

Comment: Thank you for those links. I just have one more question about vertex normals. So when a vertex normal is in the direction of a light source, does that mean that vertex will receive the most light? is that the reason why we use vertex normals?

Comment: @Soon_to_be_code_master - For flat shading, that's probably correct.  However, there are many different types of shading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shading#Flat_shading